# Jscrollpane does not working two at a time :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, jscrollpane

here is my problem http://www.athimannil.com/mobjob/test/news.php

scrollbar does not working on one tab

if u click on Digital news tab before complete loading of the page then it is working fine at the same time twitter tabe doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling doc ready 4 times, try once:

```
$(function(){

$('#event_scroll').tinyscrollbar();
$('#twitter_scroll').tinyscrollbar();   
$('#news_feed').tinyscrollbar();

// Tabs
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({event: "mouseover"});
});
```